# how to calculate total bytes in cache?

Tags: caching, computer-science, processor

I have the question does anyone know how calculate the total amount of bytes in cache if the byte main memory is 2 MB and the block size is 32 Bytes. Using direct mapping with 32 lines?

Really hard to understand what and how it is done.

Thanks.

Comment: Debatable whether this is a development question or just a math/theory question.  Probably better on a different stackexchange site?

Answer (score 0):

The purpose here is to cache some of the data the processor needs in memory. Similarly, there may be a cache between the data in the memory and the disk.

In this case, if a data is needed from the disk, the faster memory can be loaded into the memory by booting. There are of course two possibilities: Hit: hit, cache of the processor's request Miss: lost, access to the memory of the processor's request can not be made from the cache.

The ratios of these numbers also have the following values: hit ratio = hit / hit + miss) Miss ratio = miss / total demand (or hit + loss) For example, suppose that 45 memory access requests and 21 of them are in cache.

In this case, miss = 45 - 21 = 24 hit ratio = 21/45 = 47% loss ratio = 24/45 = 53%

#can you put a plus?